# on rotate android screen onclick button instead of adding new items, it will delete the previous itesm

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, screen-orientation

ok the app has 1 button onclick will add item to arraylist and then to firebase but when i rotate screen an click same button, instead of adding more items, will delete all items created before rotating screen then will add items again.
here is my button code

```
conver_textview_to_string=new ArrayList<>();
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    conver_textview_to_string.add("123");
                    for(int i=0;i<conver_textview_to_string.size();i++){
                        myRef.setValue(conver_textview_to_string);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On screen rotation the `Activity` is recreated, so in-order for you to save previous data(before screen rotation), you have to store your data/values inside `onSaveInstanceState`  and get its value inside `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("myText", conver_textview_to_string);
    }

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    conver_textview_to_string = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("myText");    
}
```

Comment: thank you but conver_textview_to_string gives red line error will try to see why even my array list declare is global.

Comment: Try using `outState.putStringArrayList` and `savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList`, i think this will solve your issue

Comment: Thanks friend you are supper star but now i noticed new problem when i exit the app and relaunched same problem as before first delete everything then add new one?

Comment: That is because all data that you stored in memory are cleared by Android OS. In-order to maintain those data, make them persist using `Database/SharedPreference/Files/Server`

Comment: any link or detail to follow i do not know it at all. thank you, but i thought firebase is database when u store data it will be there unless u delete it yourself

Comment: I suggest you to go through Firebase documentation, it is really helpful and helps in storage & retrieval of data. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once

Answer (score 2):

> put this in your menifest.xml where you Register your Activity

Replace MyActivity with your Activity name

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Aniruddh Parihar thanks for quick response but was not working still same problem

Comment: Try android:configChanges="orientation | screensize"

Comment: thanks Aniruddh your new answer aswell works but i had to get rid of the space between seperators and s letter of screen should be capital, but work thank you

Answer (score 1):

With default configuration the Activity is destroyed and recreated each time the screen is rotated. You can do two things:

- Save activity state in a Bundle overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and then restoring state with the Bundle passed as argument on `onCreate` or overriding `onRestoreInstanceState`
- adding `android:configChanges="orientation | screensize"` for your activity in your manifest.xml . That makes the activity will not be recreated on screen rotation.

Comment: thanks Tonteria your answer aswell works with some changes get rid of space between pipes and make s of size capital so its screenSize thanks to all